# How can I compute energy from a protein PDB file?

Tags: proteins, pdb

Suppose I have a protein PDB file and want to compute energy using the following formula from the coordinates in the file.

[image]

**How can I do that?**

Sometimes people suggest using the `CONECT` field for that purpose. However, some PDB files do not have this field.

Example: [4OSK.pdb (Crystal structure of TAL effector reveals the recognition between asparagine and guanine)](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4osk)

Comment: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11678/how-can-i-retrieve-bond-information-froma-protein-pdb-file

Comment: https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe-srv/pdbechem/bond/list/CYS Molecule : CYS    

Bonds between two atoms of the molecule , then of course in each protein chain you'll have a Nterminal and Cterminal residues and all the ones in between having a peptide bond CO-N between Cter and Nter

Comment: http://ligand-expo.rcsb.org/pyapps/ldHandler.py?formid=cc-index-search&target=cys&operation=ccid here with pics http://ligand-expo.rcsb.org/reports/C/CYS/CYS_D3L1.gif

Comment: think you'll need to create a dictionary for each residue

Comment: see here for better explanation https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/162689/118509