# How does BioJava retrieve bond information from a PDB file?

Tags: pdb, java

[How can I compute energy from a protein PDB file?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/21614/how-can-i-retrieve-bond-information-from-a-protein-pdb-file)

I asked the above question.

Then I thought, Why don't I check how BioJava obtains bond information from a protein PDB file?

Surprisingly, BioJava's tutorial [doesn't have any discussion on Bonds](https://github.com/biojava/biojava-tutorial/blob/master/structure/README.md).

I checked [BioJava's GitHub repo](https://github.com/biojava/biojava), but I failed to find any such information.

How does BioJava retrieve bond information from a PDB file?